# Options on modelling a hazard function with a turning point

Tags: survival, hazard, proportional-hazards, accelerated-failure-time

I have some survival data and need to fit survival models to it and extrapolate. I plotted the log cumulative hazard and empirical hazard plot (using muhaz). There appears to be a change in the hazard around 400 days, but the two curves appear to be parallel.

I'm considering my options as, fitting standard proportional hazards models (exponential, Weibull, Gompertz), account for the turning point in the hazard with accelerated failure time models (log-logistic, log normal, generalised Gamma) and also using a spline with 1 know around 400 days. I was also considering a piecewise approach with two exponentials as it looks as the hazards are constant before and after the turning point.

I have a few questions around my approaches.

1. Does what I suggested, given the plots below, look reasonable?
2. The log cumulative hazard plot can determine whether hazards are proportional and a join vs two separate models for each arms are appropriate. What plot exists for modelling AFT models jointly or independently?
3. Is it possible to extrapolate a spline model?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although the baseline hazard isn't constant over time, a Weibull or some other parametric model (_not_ a simple exponential model) might handle that adequately on its own. Try that first and edit the question to show the results. It seems that your proposed approaches might be unnecessarily complicated. Be warned that extrapolation of any survival model is inherently risky, whether a simple parametric model or a spline model. "Natural" regression splines extrapolate linearly beyond the outermost knots.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure what results did you want to see?

Comment: Try fitting standard parametric models and show how well they fit your data. See for example Chapters 18 and 19 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/parsurv.html#sec-parsurv-assess-homog). For AFT models I'm fond of the Kaplan-Meier-type plots of normalized right-censored residuals (Figs 18.10 and 19.4), but any reasonable documentation of fit (or lack thereof) will do.